# Fullcalendar event's end time is missing

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I run Fullcalendar wih this options

```
defaultEventMinutes:30,
timeFormat: 'HH:mm { - HH:mm}',
```

I have some events (30 min long each), but only their start time is shown.

```
10:00 -  
14:30 -
```

while dragging an event, its start **and** endtime appears as i should be.

```
10:00 - 10:30  
14:30 - 15:00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason is that FullCalendar puts the title into the time div when there's not enough space to show the title on a separate line (which is typically the case when an event only spans 30 minutes). When the time and the title are placed in the same div, FullCalendar only passes the start time to the date formatter.

To make it work you could change line number 4020 in fullcalendar.js (v. 1.6.1) from:

```
eventElement.find('div.fc-event-time')
                        .text(formatDate(event.start, opt('timeFormat')) + ' - ' + event.title);
```

to

```
eventElement.find('div.fc-event-time')
                        .text(formatDates(event.start, event.end, opt('timeFormat')) + ' - ' + event.title);
```

If you don't want to change the source code of FullCalendar, you could instead look into the [`eventRender`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback.

---

## Updated answer

It's probably better to fix this without changing the source code of FullCalendar, and it's actually pretty simple to do it "the right way". However, the `eventRender` is not too useful, because FullCalendar collapses the time and title after this callback and our changes would be overwritten.

Luckily there's another callback [`eventAfterRender`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/) which can be used:

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, $el, view) {
    var formattedTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDates(event.start, event.end, "HH:mm { - HH:mm}");
    // If FullCalendar has removed the title div, then add the title to the time div like FullCalendar would do
    if($el.find(".fc-event-title").length === 0) {
        $el.find(".fc-event-time").text(formattedTime + " - " + event.title);
    }
    else {
        $el.find(".fc-event-time").text(formattedTime);
    }
}
```

Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvakulo/zutPu/

Comment: @ Regin Larsen "When the time and the title are placed in the same div, FullCalendar only passes the start time to the date formatter." thanks, i didnt know that.

Answer (score 8):

The answer of Regin did not work for me (I assume a newer version of FullCalendar).

I've found two solutions.

First, the easiest one that maintains most of the styling for short events. This styles it back to the defaults:

```
.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time span {
    display: inline;
}

.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:before {
    content: normal;
}  

.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:after {
    content: normal;
}
```

Secondly you could add the following logic to the eventAfterRender. Please note this might have other effects where certain styling of small items will be different, but if this is not a big issue in your environment then this works perfectly.

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, $el, view) {
                $el.removeClass('fc-short');
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

FullCalendar v3.0.0

```
.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:before {
  content: attr(data-full);
}

.fc-time-grid-event.fc-short .fc-time:after {
  content: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the updated versions of FullCalendar from v 2.4.0 there is an option "displayEventTime" which can be used to set the time whether to display in the events.

Here is the [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventTime/).

By setting this globally one can hide the time being displayed in the events.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that myself at that time and have used Full Calendar till 2019 May. It was functional. Let me know your exact requirements

Answer (score -2):

fullcalendar `2.1xxxx` display `end time`

edit line `5689`

```
return calendar.formatDate(start, opt('timeFormat'));
```

to

```
return calendar.formatRange(start, end, opt('timeFormat'));
```