# Fullcalendar - Half Hour Event Title Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

> The answer at [Fullcalendar event's end time is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936259/fullcalendar-events-end-time-is-missing) is for an older version of fullcalendar. It's not the answer I want.

In my fullcalendar application, when I create a "half-an-hour" event it just show only event start time and title at week view.

For one hour and longer events, there are no problems I encounter. It only happens at "half-an-hour" events. So, I don't know if this is a feature or not.

I want my events to be displayed like "08:00 - 08:30" (start - end) even for half an hour events.

My code:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  allDaySlot: false,
  eventOverlap: false,
  selectOverlap: false,
  editable: false,
  eventStartEditable: false,
  eventDurationEditable: false,
  timezone: 'local',
  timeFormat: "HH:mm",
  minTime: "08:00:00",
  maxTime: "20:00:00",
  header: header,
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: false,
  defaultView: "agendaWeek",
  header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
  },
  view: {
      agendaWeek: {
          columnFormat: "M/D [(]ddd[)]"
      }
  },
  select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      ...
  }
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      ...
  }
});
```

ScreenShot (SS):
[image]

Note: Sometimes even event titles cannot be seen in the week view of Fullcalendar.

Comment: I think it doesn't have enough room to display all the events data. So it justs displays the start date and the event's title. So what is your question here? Do you want to display some other informations when there's not enough room?

Comment: I want to display event start date and end date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar event's end time is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936259/fullcalendar-events-end-time-is-missing)

Comment: This post actually was solving my issue. But the thing is, formatDate() and formatDates() functions are no longer supported by fullcalendar v2 (docs says they are for v1.3). And my application version is v2.4.0. Thanks for your help.