# How to show end time in the Month section in full calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm not able to view  the end time in the Month section in my calendar.I have tried numerous examples still not able to fix it.I'm able to view my end time when I choose Day section.For example check these screenshot
[image: This is the screenshot of Month Section]

[image: This is the screenshot of Day Section]

**This is my view code:**

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;

            var event_array = [];

            var selectedEvent = null;
            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
            function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
                events = [];

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetEvents",
                    //data: { 'id': selectedId },
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");

                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            event_array.push({
                                userid: v.UserId,
                                start: moment(v.LoginTime),

                                end: moment(v.LogoutTime),
                                allDay: true,
                                eventAfterRender: function (event, $el, view) {
                                    $el.removeClass('fc-short');
                                }

                            });

                        })

                        GenerateCalender(event_array);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })
        }

        function GenerateCalender(event_array) {

            //$('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calendar').empty();
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 400,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: event_array,
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    selectedEvent = calEvent;
                    $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.userid);
                    var $description = $('<div/>');
                    $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>LoginTime:</b>' + calEvent.logintime.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    if (calEvent.end != null) {
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>LogoutTime:</b>' + calEvent.logouttime.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                    }
                    //$description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                    //$('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                    $('#myModal').modal();
                },
                selectable: true,
                select: function (logintime, logouttime) {
                selectedEvent = {
                    userid: 0,
                    logintime: logintime,
                    logouttime: logouttime,
                    allDay: true

                };
                openAddEditForm();
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventDrop: function (event) {
                var data = {
                    UserId: event.userid,
                    LoginTime: event.logintime.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                    //LogoutTime: event.logouttime.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                    LogoutTime: event.logouttime.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') 

                };
                SaveEvent(data);
                }

            });
        }

    });
    </script>
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;
    int isessionid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);
    List<SelectListItem> userList = Getuser();
    if (isessionid == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {

        //int userid = int.Parse(username);

        RegMVCEntities svc = new RegMVCEntities();
        svc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        svc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        // var oCampaigns = svc.User_LogTime;
        var oReturn =
            (from c in svc.User_LogTime.AsEnumerable()
            where c.UserId == isessionid
            select new 
            {
                LoginTime = c.LoginTime,
                Logouttime = c.LogoutTime
            }).ToList();
        //var events = dc.User_LogTime.ToList();
        //dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        //   dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return new JsonResult { Data = oReturn.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }



}
```

I have tried the fixes in [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936259/fullcalendar-events-end-time-is-missing) still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by just adding

```
displayEventEnd: true
```

In my code.This is my code

```
  $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                                contentHeight: 400,
                                displayEventEnd: true,

                                defaultDate: new Date(),
                                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                                header: {
                                    left: 'prev,next today',
                                    center: 'title',
                                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                                },
```

Answer (score 0):

you just change allday value to false

```
selectedEvent = {
    userid: 0,
    logintime: logintime,
    logouttime: logouttime,
    allDay: false
};
```

Comment: I have made allday value to False still it wont solve my issue.Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Update your GenerateCalender function :

```
 function GenerateCalender(events) {

                                    $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                                    $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                                        contentHeight: 400,
                                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                                        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                                        header: {
                                            left: 'prev,next today',
                                            center: 'title',
                                            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                                        },
                                        eventLimit: true,
                                        eventColor: '#378006',
                                        events: events,
                                        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                                            $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                                            var $description = $('<div/>');
                                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start :  </b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a")));
                                            if (calEvent.end != null) {
                                                $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End :  </b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a")));
                                            }
                                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description :  </b>' + calEvent.description));
                                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Status :  </b>' + calEvent.Status));
                                            $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                                            $('#myModal').modal();
                                        }
```